# Trigger a Email to a member who submit the form and internal Sales representative

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, triggered-send

We have a custom Cloud page form. When someone submits the form that data is captured in Data Extension.

I need to send a confirmation email with all details entered in the form to a member and also need to send an internal Sales representative Emails with all the details of a member who submit the form so, that sales resp will contact the member?

how do we achieve this in Salesforce marketing cloud?

Comment: Checkout Zuzanna's article: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/29/send-a-triggered-email-using-ampscript/

Comment: @RachidMamai thanks for the information. It will definitely help. How can I send it to internal sales rep at the same time?

Comment: You do two triggered send calls. One that is sent to the person captured and another that is sent to the agent.